# g++ can't find installed library

Tags: c++, path, compilation, g++

I'm trying to compile and example file which needs the required library libmusicxml.

I compiled the library as they said (cmake, make, make install) and it made and installed a bunch of files:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libmusicxml2.so.3.00
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libmusicxml2.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/musicxmlfactory.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/sortvisitor.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/xmlreader.h
... etc
```

Now I want to compile one of their sample files so I run g+ filename.cpp and it gives me the following error:

```
libmusicxml.h: No such file or directory
```

Does this mean it's not seeing the library in /usr/local? Can I specify this somewhere? Set a path or something?

I have made sure to have the latest version of the libmusicxml library from [here](https://github.com/dfober/libmusicxml) and did the same (cmake followed by make).

When I go to the gives samples and try to make one (with the provided make file, which work according to the developer) it doesn't want to do it:

```
dorien@XP:~/bin/libmusicxml-master/samples$ make
gcc -g -O3 -Wall -Wuninitialized -I../src/elements -I../src/interface -I../src/files -I../src/lib -I../src/parser -I../src/visitors -I../src/guido -I../src/operations countnotes.cpp ../libmusicxml2.a -lstdc++ -o countnotes
gcc: error: ../libmusicxml2.a: No such file or directory
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'countnotes' failed
```

-> I tried to locate libmusicxml2.a and that doesn't seem to exist.

When I run xml2guido (which seems to have a compiled version in the root directory of the package), I get:

```
xml2guido: error while loading shared libraries: libmusicxml2.so.3.00: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, there is a libmusicxml2.so.3.00 in the same directory

Maybe it's that the package is not linked correctly? Or something about the missing .a file?

I do think it was built correctly:

```
 make
[ 73%] Built target musicxml2
[ 75%] Built target RandomMusic
[ 78%] Built target countnotes
[ 80%] Built target partsummary
[ 82%] Built target readunrolled
[ 85%] Built target xml2guido
[ 87%] Built target xml2midi
[ 90%] Built target xmlclone
[ 92%] Built target xmlfactory
[ 95%] Built target xmliter
[ 97%] Built target xmlread
[100%] Built target xmltranspose

dorien@XP:~/bin/libmusicxml-master$ sudo make install
[ 73%] Built target musicxml2
[ 75%] Built target RandomMusic
[ 78%] Built target countnotes
[ 80%] Built target partsummary
[ 82%] Built target readunrolled
[ 85%] Built target xml2guido
[ 87%] Built target xml2midi
[ 90%] Built target xmlclone
[ 92%] Built target xmlfactory
[ 95%] Built target xmliter
[ 97%] Built target xmlread
[100%] Built target xmltranspose
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libmusicxml2.so.3.00
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libmusicxml2.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/musicxmlfactory.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/sortvisitor.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/xmlreader.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/xmlfile.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/libmusicxml.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/unrolled_xml_tree_browser.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/xml.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/elements.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/factory.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/types.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/typedefs.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/xml_tree_browser.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/versions.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/libmusicxml/exports.h
```

Comment: This means it doesn't see the file `libmusicxml.h` in `/usr/local/include/libmusicxml/` Maybe you Need to write `#include <libmusicxml/libmusicxml.h>`

Comment: You should use `-I` to specify the search path as `-I/usr/local/include`.

Comment: -L won't work. this is a missing header not a library.

Comment: @skypjack The error is not about the *.so file but about the *.h file. So it should be `-I/usr/local/include/libmusicxml`... But /usr/local/include is a Standard include path. it should work without `-I`

Comment: you are right, fixed. it could be that the file is under `libmusicxml` indeed.

Comment: did you forget to add -lmusqicxml?

Comment: Can you give your compilation command?

Comment: you must add to the link command. Or g++ filename.cpp -I/path/to/header -lmusicxml

Comment: Mmmm I tried compiling with  g++ xml2guido.cpp -I/usr/local/include/libmusicxml -Imusicxml and it keeps giving me an error: 
/tmp/ccpbD48c.o: In function `main':
xml2guido.cpp:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `musicxmlfd2guido'
xml2guido.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `musicxmlfile2guido'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library (and headers) weren't recognised until I ran:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/addressto/libmusicxml-master
```

That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean it's not seeing the library in /usr/local?

It means that it didn't find the header `libmusicxml.h`. You didn't tell the compiler to look for it in `/usr/local/include/libmusicxml`.

> Can I specify this somewhere? Set a path or something?

See the documentation of your compiler. In gcc, the option for include search paths is `-I`.

Instead of searching for the header `libmusicxml.h` from `/usr/local/include/libmusicxml/`, I would recommend including `libmusicxml/libmusicxml.h` and searching from `/usr/local/include`. That would be simpler since g++ searches from `/usr/local/include` by default, so no compiler options would be required.

Comment: oh waw, of course, I'm too used to having automatic make files... will try it right away.

Comment: When compiling with  g++ xml2guido.cpp -I/usr/local/include/libmusicxml
It gives me a different error now. It can't find a function that's specified int the libmusicxml header. In function main': xml2guido.cpp:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to musicxmlfd2guido' xml2guido.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `musicxmlfile2guido' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status